# How to simplify a multiplicator that currently consists of many adders?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, logisim

I have created a circuit with 64 AND gates, 77 1-bit adders and one OR gate. I am trying to create a 8 by 8 multiplier. How can I simplify this circuit, especially using the 8-bit adders?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Hint : how fast do you need it to be?

Comment: at this point, I am not worried about the speed. I just would like to simplify the circuit

Answer (score 1):

If speed isn't a concern, you could use an accumulator and repeatedly shift and add the multiplicand to the accumulator rather than use parallel multiplication. It should at most take 8 clock cycles, but if that's too many, you can cut that down by using a 2bit x 2bit or 4bit x 4bit parallel multiplier in conjunction with the accumulator.

Here's a Logisim circuit of an 8-bit multiplier that shifts and adds 8 times to find the product of two 8-bit inputs. It just calculated 5 * 6 to be 30
[image: 8-bit multiplier]